# push notification android with gcm

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop an android application having push up notification. the notification will be shown when admin upload new in the website or announce message in the admin account in mobile application. Generally speaking, I want the push up notification done by website and mobile application. 
I have searched almost for 3 days but it is difficult to do it successfully. I know GCM can do this. But I do not know how to use it properly. I have watched many tutorial video but it does not work. Is there anybody has experience doing push up notification in android using GCM. Can you teach me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

1) find out your device's GCM token
2) send a push notification to that device using a software like POSTMAN or a CURL command (push notifications are actually REST requests)
3) set up your backend to actually do step #2
4) Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/push-notification-using-gcm-in-android.html) to learn how to use Push Notification using GCM in Android Studio.

You can learn here the step by step procedure on how to setup your project with push notification.

- creating a project on Google Developer Console
- enable the Google Cloud messaging API
- generate the server key and project number for further use
- register the app from android using the project number
- Google will return a registration ID send this ID to your server
- send message from your server to GCM to corresponding registration ID
- GCM will send you push message through BroadCast Receiver and show it as a notification

This tutorial also includes some picture for the developers to learned easily in setting up the project.

> Note that this service is only available for small messages to the
>   client applications: 4096 Bytes is the limit, so only lightweight
>   information can be sent.